# How to access a function or variable in a script run with $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, javascript-namespaces

Is there some way to access the namespace of a script after it is run with `$.getScript`? Since `plugin` is defined in the global scope, I would have thought I'd be able to run it.

***index.js***

```
$.getScript('plugin.js').then((...result) => console.log(result));

$.getScript('plugin.js').then(plugin());
```

***plugin.js***

```
function plugin()
{
  console.log("plugin.js");
  return "plugin";
}
```

_**output**__

```
ReferenceError: plugin is not defined
    at https://replit.org/data/web_hosting_uncache/abalter/loading-scripts-and-callbacks-1/index.js:5:25
[ 'var plugin = function()\n{\n  console.log("plugin.js");\n  return "plugin";\n}',
  'success',
  Promise {
    readyState: 4,
    getResponseHeader: [Function],
    getAllResponseHeaders: [Function],
    setRequestHeader: [Function],
    overrideMimeType: [Function],
    statusCode: [Function],
    abort: [Function],
    state: [Function],
    always: [Function],
    catch: [Function],
    pipe: [Function],
    then: [Function],
    promise: [Function],
    progress: [Function],
    done: [Function],
    fail: [Function],
    responseText: 'var plugin = function()\n{\n  console.log("plugin.js");\n  return "plugin";\n}',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'success' } ]
```

https://repl.it/@abalter/loading-scripts-and-callbacks-1

Comment: `plugin` is not in scope when it's used. You're passing the result of invoking plugin as the argument to then.  it doesn't make sense. You want `$.getScript('plugin.js').then(() => window.plugin());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
$.getScript('plugin.js').then(plugin());
```

`then` accepts a *function* as an argument, not a *function call* (unless said function call is a call to a higher-order function that returns a function to be put in the promise chain)

You're calling `plugin()` at the same moment you're making the script request. You don't want that - you want to call `plugin` only after the request has finished. But at the time the `getScript` runs, `plugin` isn't defined in window scope yet. Inside of `then`, put a function that *runs* `plugin` once called:

```
$.getScript('plugin.js').then(() => plugin());
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still confused about receiving a function as an argument. For instance, this does not work: `$.getScript('plugin.js').then(x => x());` or `$.getScript('plugin.js').then((x) => x());` .

Comment: The data does not automatically resolve to a single function that can be called like that - I think it's just the response. But if it's been put into the global namespace already, you don't want to execute the fetched script again; you just want to call the object that was added to `window`.

Answer (score 1):

You are invoking the function immediately in:

```
$.getScript('plugin.js').then(plugin());
```

Change to

```
$.getScript('plugin.js').then(_ => plugin());
```